# Spring boot 3, Spring security с базовой аутентификацией и CSRF токеном

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-security

Пытаюсь разобраться с REST запросами. Есть небольшое приложение после аутентификации и авторизации success handler отправляет на обычный класс контроллера с вьюшками, /users далее открывается HTML-страница с подключенным JavaScript. При на нажатии на кнопку test, которая на странице users.html, JavaScript отправляет post запрос на другой класс REST контроллер v3/API/users. Запрос до REST контроллера не доходит, ошибка 405. Если метод с REST API поместить в контроллер /users то все хорошо. Если оставить отдельным классом то ошибка 405. Подскажите почему так?